# Why My hibernate4 session.save() can only be called once，cannot be called continuously

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Those are my relate code.I have hibernate4.2.6+spring3.2.4

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="#{proConfig.driverClass}"/>
        ......
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="#{proConfig.testConnectionOnCheckin}"/>
</bean>  
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
                org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <value>
            com.xxx.xxx.dao.FilmUrl
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="downloadTaskWith" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        ......
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="daoMethods" expression="execution(* com.xxxx.xxxx.service.impl.*.*(..))" />
    <!-- 定义了将采用何种拦截操作，这里引用到 txAdvice -->
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="daoMethods" />
</aop:config>
```

My FilmUrl:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_download_film_url",catalog="crawlertest")
public class FilmUrl implements Serializable {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id",unique = true,nullable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="url",length = 45)
    private String url;
    @Column(name="isHandle")
    private int isHandle;
    @Column(name="type")
    private int type;
    @Id
    public int getId() {
    ....
    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

My DAO:

```
@Repository
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, ID> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected GenericDaoImpl(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    private Session currentSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public ID saveEntity(T entity) {
        return (ID)currentSession().save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveEntityBatch(Collection<T> objects) {
        for (T entity:objects){
            currentSession().save(entity);
//            currentSession().flush();
//            currentSession().clear();
        }
    }
```

That's all.In my DAO.saveEntity function works well,saveEntityBatch cannot work.
If I let currentSession().flush(); and currentSession().clear() be after currentSession().save(entity) ,It's OK.But commenting them,It will be blocked.
Why?So I am here for some help.
Thank you~

Comment: Define "it will be blocked". What happens *precisely*? Also: fix your mapping. The mapping annotations should be on getter, or on fields, but not on both.

Comment: @RomanC: read the question, its title and its tags. He's using Hibernate.

Comment: @JBNizet ok, can you tell me why saveEntityBatch doesn't work?

Comment: @RomanC: read my above comment. I asked the OP to precisely define what the problem is. "it doesn't work" or "it will be blocked" aren't precise descriptions of what happens.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you very very much！！！I have solve my problem！You say：“The mapping annotations should be on getter, or on fields, but not on both。” It's the right answer and why my program cannot work。Thank you！

Comment: Try to flush the session and recreate session to have batch upload..Have a look at my answer below..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code. Here I am clearing and flushing the session by checking the batch size that is set during when we set the other properties of Hibernate.

```
/**
 * @param entityList
 * @param batchSize
 * @return
 */
public long batchUpdate(final List<DomainObject> entityList, long batchSize) {
    Long insertedCount = 0L;
    for (int i = 0; i < entityList.size(); ++i) {
        update(entityList.get(i));
        if (++insertedCount % batchSize == 0) {
            flushAndClear();
        }
    }
    flushAndClear();
    return insertedCount;
}

/**
 * Flush and clear.
 */
void flushAndClear() {
    if (getSession().isDirty()) {
        getSession().flush();
        getSession().clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi，Thank you for your answer。@JBNizet Has solved my problem。I shouldn't put mapping annotation on the both field。